# JQuery $(this) not working inside a function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code doesn't work:

```
$(".countdown").circularCountdown({

    startDate:$(this).attr('data-start'),
    endDate:$(this).attr('data-end'),
    timeZone:$(this).attr("timezone")

});
```

The one below works fine,

```
$(".countdown").circularCountdown({

    startDate:$(".countdown").attr('data-start'),
    endDate:$(".countdown").attr('data-end'),
    timeZone:$(".countdown").attr("timezone")

});
```

I don't get it, doesn't the $(this) reference ".countdown" since I'm calling the function on this element? Could someone please help me out?

Comment: $(this) doesn't refer to $('.countdown'). it refers to the 'this' of the surrounding closure. Read up on 'closure' and 'scope' to find out why :-)

Comment: It's refreshing to see a well asked question from a user with low rep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `this` does not refer to the `countdown` so one solution is to use `each()`

```
$(".countdown").each(function () {
    $(this).circularCountdown({
        startDate: $(this).attr('data-start'),
        endDate: $(this).attr('data-end'),
        timeZone: $(this).attr("timezone")
    });
})
```

Comment: I would've made the code exactly how i editted your version. ($this instead of $(this)). However, stating you *need* to use `each` is incorrect.

Comment: ah yeah, my bad, didnt refresh yet :-) good call! for obvious reasons: `var $this = $(this); $this.circ ....`

Comment: The one thing that I think is missing from this answer is that fact that `this` will only be set to what the OP expects when you call a jQuery method that expects a callback, because jQuery sets `this`. Which is exactly what you did. The one problem with this approach is that there's really no need to do each, you're calling `circularCountown` on your own multiple times instead of letting the jQuery object do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is usually bound to an element that is clicked, hovered, etc. I believe you must specify or select the element which has  'data-start' attribute prior to using $(this) selector. Could you provide more information on how you are running this function and your html structure?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling function on it, you are calling a plugin. So you write in the json parameters which don't know what is the the object. I strongly agree with Arun P Johny that this is the way. If you want to go deep you can change in the plugin those values

```
 startDate: $(this).attr('data-start'),
 endDate: $(this).attr('data-end'),
 timeZone: $(this).attr("timezone")
```

And it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Within your object initialiser, "this" refers to the execution context of the currently executing function, which is the function in which your call to circularCountdown is made, or (and this is what I would assume is most likely the case) the global context by default if the call is not inside a function.

You could solve your problem like this:

```
 $(".countdown").each(function() {

       var start = $(this).attr('data-start'),
              end = $(this).attr('data-end'),
              time = $(this).attr("timezone");

       $(this).circularCountdown({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            timeZone: time
      });

 });
```

jQuery's each method allows you to pass in a function to initialise each of your elements in turn, with access to the element currently being initialised through "this".

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `$(".countown")`and `$(this)` at (almost) the same time. Therefore, `this` points to whatever it pointed to when you called `$(".countown")`

**Visual Example**

```
var currentThis = this;
$(".countdown").circularCountdown({

    startDate:$(this).attr('data-start'), // "this" is the same as "currentThis"
    endDate:$(this).attr('data-end'),
    timeZone:$(this).attr("timezone")

});
```

You are probably thinking of jQuery functions where you pass a callback. In that case, jQuery sets `this` in the callback to point to the object that the function was called on. Just like [Arun mentioned with $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25079074/227299)

Another solution is to save it to a variable, you don't want to run the same query four times.

```
var ctDown = $(".countdown");
ctDown.circularCountdown({    
    startDate: ctDown.attr('data-start'),
    endDate: ctDown.attr('data-end'),
    timeZone: ctDown.attr("timezone")

});
```

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one element with the class "countdown". Without seeing the code of the circularCountdown plugin, jQuery's each method (not $.each, which is a 'static' function with a slightly different purpose) seems the best way to go to me.

Comment: @BenGriffiths That's true. Except that according the OP's example, there is only one on the page (because they are using `$(this).attr('data-start')` which will only get the attribute for the first one). But your point is a valid one.